# javascript/jquery changing html element based on value entered into text input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It sounds simple but I am a novice with Javascript and I am having a very tough time trying to find / create this script. I have a list of BIN numbers for credit cards and am trying to grab the first 6 digits of the card number field and check to see what kind of card it is, then displaying the appropriate card logo on screen based on the BIN entered.

I have been able to create a very simple script which checks the input and can change a value or element, but I have not figured out how to do the reverse. I need to be able to remove the card logo and replace it if the user deletes the card and re-enters the card info.

Here is very simple demo.
http://jsfiddle.net/6HmxM/653/

```
$( "input" )

  .keyup(function() {
  if ($( "input" ).val() == 45) {
      var val = "Visa";
  } 
  $( "p" ).text( val )
})
```

Comment: Both of those answers work, depending on if you prefer using a `switch` or `if..else if` set of functions.  I like this idea of the image appearing and disappearing with input.

Comment: So far I like sbeliv01 answer the best, simple and working.

Comment: @JustAGuy okay just make sure to handle the case when those digits show up later on; for example, in sbeliv01's last fiddle if you were to type in "1234567" visa would still show up even though those 4 digits `4567` don't happen at the first of the string rather later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably best to use a `switch` in this case to print out a default, which is probably blank. Just set up each case to print out what you want otherwise it will default to whatever is defined in `default:`.

```
$( "input" )

  .keyup(function() {

      var $value = $(this).val(),
          output = "";

      switch( $value ) {

          case "45" :
              output = "Visa";
          break;

          case "44" :
              output = "Mastercard";
          break;

          default:
              output = "Nothing";
              break;


      }

      $( "p" ).text( output )
  })
```

Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/6HmxM/655/

Although, you might have to make adjustments to the `switch` if you're going based on the first 6 characters, likely a RegEx to match the first six, since the `output` will be nothing unless there is an exact match on every key stroke. In which case you'll likely need something like this:

```
$( "input" )

  .keyup(function() {

      var $value = $(this).val(),
          output = "";

      switch( true ) {

          case /4567/.test($value) :
              output = "Visa";
          break;

          case /4412/.test($value) :
              output = "Mastercard";
          break;

          default:
              output = "Nothing";
          break;

       }

      $( "p" ).text( output )
  })
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/6HmxM/656/

Comment: That's great i'm just wondering how you would do the RegEx to only show the output if it matches the `first six digits`?

Comment: This works great! I didn't think the javascript would be so simple. One more question for you though, I can easily switch the text for the div using the sample code above, would be difficult to change value of an HTML img src for each case as well? I want to display the logo as well, which was not present in my jsfiddle example. Here is an updated example using your case to switch text. http://jsfiddle.net/6HmxM/658/

Comment: FYI - Turns out I don't need to match the full BIN, the first two digits are enough to identify the card number. Currently the case switch script above is dynamically changing the values, so seems to be working. I just need to take a bit further by changing HTML img element as well.    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Issuer_Identification_Numbers#Banking_and_financial_.284.2A.2A.2A.2A.2A.29